# c# about struct

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains variables and lists. Ex:

```
public class x:Form        
{
    private a=null;
    private list<xy> o=null;
    otherclass cl=null;

    public x()
    {
        ..code
    }
    ...
}
```

If I want to have this multiple times. I have 2 different form application that access this members. I would like to have somethinng like this: `something[0].x; something[1].x.` What should I do? Should i create a structure? Thx for help!. I would appreciate if you can give me examples using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it as a array or a List

```
x[] something = new x[2];
```

This is the best solution if you know there will always be 2 instances and no more.

Or a list

```
List<x> something = new List<x>();
something.Add( firstX );
something.Add( secondX );
```

This will make it easy to add extra instances of x to the list, or delete existing ones, so it's a more dynamic variant than the array.

Comment: @elisa - Instances of x. You have to make the x'es seperately and insert them into the list. So at least `x firstX = new x();` and `x secondX = new x();`

Comment: Ok thx:). What if i want to work with the vector inside this class? I mean i would like to have the ability to work and construct different x[1],x[2] in this x class where i am already using the list variables and so on. Wouldn't it will be better to create a vector or a structure in the x class and the in its constructor or other methods to work with structure[1].list...?

Comment: @elisa - You can of course contain all this logic inside a another class to hide the logic, but then to retain the something[0] syntax the best way is to keep the List in my answer inside the class, and in addition create an indexer for the class to retain the syntax you want to use. Link on indexers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx) class.

```
Pair something = new Pair();
something.First = firstX;
something.Second = secondX;
```